# How to stop multiple redirect in while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use if statent to trigger a database account when some conditions are met. However it runs into many redirects and crashes the site.

Here is my code;

```
    //mine starts here
$currenttime = time();
$endtime = number_format($UserDetails->interest_time);
$capital = number_format($UserDetails->deposit);
$profit =  number_format(Profit());
$earnings = $capital + $profit;
$status = number_format($UserDetails->profit_times);





if ($endtime != 0 && $currenttime > $endtime){
    $endinvestment = $royaldb->query("UPDATE user SET status=0, earnings='$earnings' WHERE id=$UserDetails->id") or die($royaldb->error);

    $usr = new Royaltechinc\Mailer;
    $usr->mailUserEnd($UserDetails->email, $UserDetails->full_name, $capital, $profit, $earnings);
    $_SESSION["alert"]='<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                      <h4><i class="fa fa-sucess"></i> Alert!</h4>
                      <h5>Your Investment has ended, You have been credit!</h5>
                    </div>';
    header("location: index.php");
    exit;
            
}
```

Comment: Does it send the email? Does it redirect to index.php? In other words, where does it "crash"?

Comment: Is this code included anywhere on index.php?

Comment: @Daan it sends the email multiple times till it crashes

Comment: @aynber Yes, it is included in the index.php

Comment: So from here, you need to fix your loop caused by this code. It loads index.php, it hits the if block, runs the script, redirects back to the index, hits the if block, runs the script, redirects back to the index, and there's your never-ending loop. You need to fix your criteria so that it only hits the if block once in some sort of interval.